# Android - Issues over UI selection tools and Integration with java

Tags: android

Hello all Android Biggers! I am AndroMinor quite new to stackoverflow having only 6 months of experience in development("Not that great"). Stuck in between Cross platform issues while trying to make a social networking android app.The question is divided into two parts:

1. Absolutely knackered in choosing good UI design tools.In store are-Adobe Air, Flash and Flex  good thing is that all of them have fantastic representation of UI and the superset- Air is quite smooth and prolific but it lacks interaction with Java as works with Actionscript.Why ?
2. I want to develop an app using Android SDK version with proper android java programming, which is however, quite possible if i follow the ethics. but i find Android sdk, a bit powerful tool for connection and other form of packages but it lacks designing structure and graphics compare to Air and Flex.Is it possible if good UI tools like Adobe Air or Flex can be combined to Java codes and rendered inside an App ?

Thanks!

Comment: Which IDE are you using, and what do you find lacking to design the UI?

Comment: Hello James! thanks for noticing. I am using Eclipse Galileo with Android 2.1 sdk. I found the colours and look with feel is very normal or traditional in the sdk as compare to Flex and Air designs.So was apparently looking for something called integration from third party in design terms and would like to continue using Java programming.

Comment: I am not clear what you find lacking.  You can create your own UI components if there was something lacking, but if you could go into more detail about what you find missing it would be helpful in trying to see how to answer you.

Comment: James, the button and layout structure of android sdk is common while using the libraries and Ofcourse Yes, i can make my own UI components using photoshop. Photoshop designs can be used with java but as far as Flex and Air is concern, they can't be as they use their own scripting language. Basically,Want to use Air or Flex design while sticking with Java codes as they are far better then Adobe Photoshop to be very precise. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for a tutorial like this:

http://dgrigg.com/blog/2010/06/23/developing-flash-applications-for-android/

You can also look at this, regarding Adobe Air being available for Android:

http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2011/02/adobe-air-2-6-for-android-is-now-available.html

You will have more limitations, in that you will probably not have access to the native API, according to this:

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110823135541AA1675d

Comment: Thanks James! Well, i got my answer from the third link up there also, other two links were quite helpful tutorials.